# CullVisitor::apply(Geode&) detected NaN,

Tags: c++, ruby, openscenegraph

I have the following message when I run my OSG application:

```
CullVisitor::apply(Geode&) detected NaN, 
    depth=nan, center=(1.79588 1.50488 1.42179), 
    matrix={ 
        nan nan -nan -nan 
        nan nan -nan -nan 
        nan nan -nan -nan 
        nan nan -nan -nan 
}
```

What this kind of warning/error means?

Thanks in advance,

Rômulo

Comment: When you cull your scene ? Is scene initialized there or not?

Comment: The unique cull I have in my code is

_viewer->getCamera()->setComputeNearFarMode(      osg::CullSettings::DO_NOT_COMPUTE_NEAR_FAR);

Comment: Can you change DONT_COMPUTE_NEAR_FAR , and test again something like COMPUTE_NEAR_USING_PRIMITIVES and test it?

Comment: Hi @CherkesgillerTural, I tested with this new parameter and the problem persists...

Comment: In my answer below, you can see that you have somekind of depth problem, solve this , i think your problem will also solved

Answer (score 2):

I found and solved the problem!

When I grab the osg scene at first time, my view matrix is NaN; from the second time, this matrix is correctly filled.

Then I perform a check: if the view matrix is invalid, I will replace it by the identity matrix, as follows:

```
   // if the view matrix is invalid (NaN), use the identity
    osg::ref_ptr<osg::Camera> camera = _viewer->getCamera();
    if (camera->getViewMatrix().isNaN())
        camera->setViewMatrix(osg::Matrix::identity());
```

Answer (score 0):

from the http://trac.openscenegraph.org/projects/osg//browser/OpenSceneGraph/trunk/src/osgUtil/CullVisitor.cpp?rev=12829

It is a problem due to **depth**, I think.

```
    RefMatrix& matrix = *getModelViewMatrix();
...
    float depth = bb.valid() ? distance(bb.center(),matrix) : 0.0f;
```

[image]

Comment: I was able to solve the problem, @Cherkesgiller, thanks for all comments.